# Check For Voltage With A Raspberry Pi 2b GPIO Pin

Tags: c#, gpio, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I want to build a simple (game)controller for my raspberry pi 2b. My plan is to connect the 3.3 voltage output to a button and than to whatever GPIO pin.

Is it possible to check for voltage with the GPIO pin? Or are there more smoother ways to build one (Analog to Digital)?

Please respect that I am developing in Visual Studio 2015 C# and my RP-OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Did you check any tutorials? The pushbutton sample is one of the first projects covered as you only need to detect high/low states

Answer (score 0):

You can read the status of the pin (High/Low) or you can use interrupts to receive events when the status changes.

The button and LED project is the very first examples either on the [Raspberry Pi site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/python-quick-reaction-game/) or [Windows IoT site](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PushButton.htm). The PushButton sample for C# uses interrupts to detect status changes.

The OS or language doesn't matter so much as the fact that you are using an RPi. In order to work with a pin, you need to open it, set its mode and then, either retrieve its value periodically ,or listen to an interrupt.

In the sample, the following steps are taken:

- Open the button pin: `buttonPin = gpio.OpenPin(BUTTON_PIN);`
- Set it as input: `buttonPin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp)`;
- Listen to the interrupt with an event handler: `buttonPin.ValueChanged += buttonPin_ValueChanged;`

Generally speaking, you should work with both Raspbian and Windows IoT to understand how RPi behaves:

- Windows IoT doesn't yet support RPi's full functionality yet so there are things that are far easier to do with Raspbian than Windows IoT, eg using temperature sensors or any device with 1-Wire support.
- Sensor manufacturers provide samples, code and even libraries for Rapsbian or Arduino. Getting the sensor to work is hard enough, you shouldn't have to translate from Raspbian to Windows IoT as well.

Comment: It's not that difficult to translate some C or Python code for a GPIO connected device example to a UWP C#. The thing which I find most annoying is what you have already mentioned. IoT doesn't support all the functionality. e.g DWP changing frequency on the board to dim the LEDs.

Comment: Didn't say it is and I don't think this either. What is frustrating though is trying to do *two* things at the same time - understand the hardware project *and* convert to UWP. When trying to find why you can't read a sensor or why a LED doesn't light, worrying about connections and misconfiguration is enough. Worrying about missing OS/Framework functionality or a bad language translation is best delayed until *after* the hardware starts working

Comment: And what's more annoying is I doubt those manufacturers will ever provide UWP examples.

Comment: You'd be surprised, or rather, they'll create Javascript examples. Manufacturers create *hardware* not software and will create whatever is more popular/easier for them. Back in the Win NT days, UPS manufacturers created Visual Basic utilities to signal power loss and start a shutdown,  rather than raise the pins expected by the OS.